# Sorting data from one table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

Here are my tables:

```
create table tableA (id int, type varchar(5))
insert into tableA (ID,TYPE)
values

    (101,'A'),
    (101,'C'),
    (101,'D'),
    (102,'A'),
    (102,'B'),
    (103,'A'),
    (103,'C')

create table tableB (id int, type varchar(5), isActive bit)
insert into tableB (id, type, isActive)
Values 

    (101,'A',1),
    (101,'B',0),
    (101,'C',0),
    (101,'D',1),

    (102,'A',1),
    (102,'B',0),
    (102,'C',1),
    (102,'D',1),

    (103,'A',1),
    (103,'B',1),
    (103,'C',1),
    (103,'D',1)
```

Now, I want to do two things here:
1) Find the rows that are present in `tableA` but `isActive = 0` in `tableB`. (done)

```
select A.* from tableA A
join tableB B
on A.id = B.id and A.type = B.type 
where B.isactive = 0
```

2) Find the rows that are missing in `tableA` but `isActive = 1` in `tableB`.
For example ID 103, type B is active in `tableB` but is missing in tableA.
I don't care about existance of type D in `tableA` because I am only checking the last entry in `tableA` which is C. 
Also, ABCD is in order for all IDs, they can be active or inactive.

Thanks for your help!

My effort: (not working)

```
select A.* from tableA A
where exists (
select B.* from tableA A
join tableB B 
on a.id = b.id 
where b.isActive = 1
order by b.id,b.type
)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f54391/1)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like the following:

```
select B.* from tableB B
left join tableA A
  on B.id = A.id and B.type = A.type
where B.isActive = 1
  and A.id is null
order by B.id, B.type
```

By using the left join, it means that rows in tableB that have no rows to join with in tableA will have all A.* columns null. This then allows you to add the where clause to check where the tableA records are null thus determining what is contained within tableB that is active and not in tableA

Comment: The result that we should really expect is 103 B from tableA because  we just want to check in tableA upto the last type for that ID. for example, for ID 101, last type is D so we should be checking for active A,B,C,D in tableB for ID 101. For ID 102, B is the last type so in tableB we are only checking A nd B for 102 and want to get in resultset if there are missing rows in tableA that were active in B.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here. The query will return values that are not in TableA but are active in TableB.